# How to convert a PDF to a PNG in IOS programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, tiles

I am developing an iPhone application to display large image(s) and PDF(s).  The PDF and images are available for web downloading or through iTunes importing.

I am using a tiling approach where after the download/import a set of PNG/JPEG tiles are programmatically generated and saved to the iPhone.

Looking previous questions I found a way to do tiling for large images, but it does not work with PDF files?

I wonder if it is possible to convert the PDF file into a PNG/JPEG before running the tiling routine, or if there are better approaches to do this.

Answer (score 8):

You can create an image object, create a graphic context for the image, render the PDF page in the image's graphic context and then save the image.